# Cannot pass params using navigate and multiple StackNavigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
  render() {
    const { icon, title, description, preview, video } = this.props;

    return (
  ....
            <Text
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation("VideoPlayer", video);
              }}
              style={styles.text}
            >
              {title}
            </Text>
```

Using seperate `stackNavigators` in a `DrawerNavigator`, in my component I use `getParam`, however, its empty, how can I pass props?

```
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const videoId = navigation.getParam("video", ''); // empty

    return (
```

AppNavigator:

```
const config = {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
        itemStyle: {
            flexDirection: "row-reverse"
        }
    },
    drawerWidth: 300,
    drawerPosition: "right"
};

const withHeader = (
    screen: Function,
    routeName: string,
    Header
): StackNavigator =>
    createStackNavigator(
        {
            [routeName]: {
                screen,
                navigationOptions: ({ navigation, routeName, props }) => ({
                    header: props => <Header {...props} />
                })
            }
        },
        {
            transparentCard: true
        }
    );

const routes = {
    Home: {
        screen: withHeader(HomeScreen, "Home", BasicHeader)
    },
    Links: {
        screen: withHeader(LinksScreen, "Links", DrawerHeader)
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: withHeader(SettingsScreen, "Settings", DrawerHeader)
    },
    VideoEpisodes: {
        screen: withHeader(VideoEpisodesScreen, "Video Episodes", DrawerHeader)
    },
    VideoPlayer: {
        screen: withHeader(VideoPlayerScreen, "Video Player", DrawerHeader)
    },
    TestYourself: {
        screen: withHeader(TestYourselfScreen, "Test Yourself", DrawerHeader)
    },
    MyResults: {
        screen: withHeader(MyResultsScreen, "My Results", DrawerHeader)
    },
    BookmarkedVideos: {
        screen: withHeader(
            BookmarkedVideosScreen,
            "Bookmarked Videos",
            DrawerHeader
        )
    },
    Search: {
        screen: withHeader(SearchScreen, "Search", DrawerHeader)
    },
    About: {
        screen: withHeader(AboutScreen, "About", DrawerHeader)
    }
};

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(routes, config);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

VideoPlayer:

```
    export default class VideoPlayerScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          video: this.props.navigation.state.params.video
        };
      }
      render() {
        console.log(this.state.video);

        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <VideoPlayer {...this.props} /> 
          </View>
        );
      }

}
```

[Snack setup here](https://snack.expo.io/@mharrisweb/insane-cake)

Comment: if you log navigation.state.params, do you see your parameter ?

Comment: Isn't it `this.props.navigation.navigate`?

Comment: @hardworker no nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by not using `props`:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Using my own function in my component:

```
function getParams() {
    const {
        nav: { index, routes }
    } = _navigator.state;

    const params = routes[index].params;
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `video` has the right value,

```js
 render() {
    const { icon, title, description, preview, video } = this.props;

    return (
  ....
            <Text
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("VideoPlayer", {video: video });
              }}
              style={styles.text}
            >
              {title}
            </Text>
```

> VideoPlayer Screen:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      video: this.props.navigation.state.params.video,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Still get params `undefined`

Comment: @Bomber If you copy my code, but it doesn't work, the video doesn't have any value. If you add the string value and test it, you will get the value.

Comment: `video` has a value, I can output it in my view, but I its undefined when I navigate to my `VideoPlayer` screen, I have added my `AppNavigator`. I am using a stack for each screen. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `navigate` is an object called `params`, and your `video` object should be a property of that object, try like this:

`this.props.c("VideoPlayer", { video });`

Comment: Still get `undefined`

Comment: Why is your function called `this.props.c`? Where is it coming from?